# Removing First Samba AD Server from the forest

Tags: samba4

we have 3 Samba AD servers, the oldest one (v4.1.12) is running on Centos 6.10; although we have add 2 more servers with current v4.15.13-Ubuntu and All the Roles switched over to one of them however unable to get rid of the oldest one i.e. user machines are still looking for it either pinging or joining the domain.

how can we switch the lookup to new server?